# setting up locations with nginx using root and index

Tags: nginx

Hi I was wondering why I keep getting a 404 error when setting up a location on my nginx server.
Below is what I am trying to do:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

      
 location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    
    }
location /api {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    
    }
```

The issue is the /api location call. I am just playing around with ngnix and was wondering why it can't find the html file. I think it is an issue with root maybe. What exactly is the root and index I need to set up to get it to work as exactly in the / location path

Comment: You want to serve the same `index.html` file from both `/` and `/api` URIs? Check the difference between the `root` and `alias` nginx directives.

Comment: ye exactly, I will

Comment: The Nginx directives are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).